NameError при завершении работы программы
Делаю консольную программу и хочу чтобы в любой момент пользователь мог написать "Выход" и программа закрылась
try:
    min_money = int(input("Минимальная сумма (если не нужна напишите 0): "))
    if min_money >= 0:
        break
    else:
        print("Минимальное число не может быть меньше 0")
except ValueError:
    if str(min_money).title() == "Выход":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Вы ввели некорректную информацию")

В общем если пользователь напишет выход программа закрывается, но вот с такой ошибкой
if str(min_money).title() == "Выход:
NameError: name 'min_money' is not defined

Нужно сначала проверять не ввёл ли пользователь "Выход", а потом уже делать все остальное.
